# How to change ODK GPS accuracy threshold?

Tags: gps, data-collection, open-data-kit

I am using ODK with ONA in XLSForm. As the GPS accuracy default is 5 meters, it automatically accepts it when it reaches 5 meter. Is it possible to change the default accuracy to less than 5 meters (i.e 3 meters)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from https://opendatakit.org/help/form-design/examples/

> By default, this widget halts the geo-positioning process once the
>   geopoint has an accuracy of 5m or less. To change this, you can supply
>   an "accuracyThreshold" attribute to the  tag. I.e., to instruct
>   ODK Collect to capture geopoints with accuracies of 1.5m or less, use:
>
> ```
> <h:body>       
>   <input ref="my_geopoint" accuracyThreshold="1.5">
>     <label>geopoint widget</label>
>     <hint>this will get gps location</hint>
>   </input>
> </h:body>
> ```

Comment: Thanks @Chris W . Where can edit this. On the form or at ODK collect. I am using a tutorial form now and will try to design my XLSform later. Thanks

Comment: @shakasom The page I linked to and got the answer from was for editing the raw XML data of a form. I'm not sure if the XLSForm designer would let you specify it (maybe as a constraint? but that doesn't sound right), but they link to another page at the top specifically for XLSForm (I skimmed it but didn't see a reference to this attribute tag).